# Laravel Eloquent, where query on child model with if statement

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Can someone help me out, I'm trying to do a `where` query on a Child Model. Everything seems fine when I have a value for the id but it returns nothing when no id is supplied.

My goal is to get all data when no id is supplied and get specific data when id supplied.

Here's my code

```
Report::with(['project'])
->whereHas('project' function($q) use($programId){ 
   if($programId){
    $q->where('program_id', $programId);
   }
})->get();
```

Is there a better way to achieve my goal? or I just lack something on the query? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think the most pragmatic way here is to make a separate query for the projects when no $programId is provided and to attach it to the report after that.

Comment: thank you for your answer @Blum, It works now but can you suggest another way where I wouldn't have to use a separate query? Just me being meticulous lol. But I will keep it for now until I have a better answer. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `when` method for this.

The `when` method only executes the given closure when the first argument is `true`. If the first argument is `false`, the closure will not be executed.

```
Report::with('project')
->when($programId, function ($query) use ($programId) {
   $query->whereHas('project' function($q) use($programId){ 
      $q->where('project.program_id', $programId);
   });
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

So I have a little complex answer for this type of questions where you can create a query and do every logic to it.

```
// Initialise the model
$query = new Report;

// Start building the query
$query->with('project');

// Check if project Id exists
if ($projectId) {
    return $query->whereHas('project', function ($subQuery) use ($projectId) {
         $subQuery->where('program_id', $programId);
    })->get();
} else {
    return $query->get();
}
```